# Override CSS of child component

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular6, styling

```
<div class="app-component">
   <child class="test">{{name}}</child>
</div>
```

and my CSS styles in child class

```
.{
   text-align:center;
}
```

and i did override in parent component i.e in app component as

```
:host /deep/ .test{
       text-align:right;
        color: red;
     }
```

so in this code only **"color:red" is working fine , but "text-align:right", which i want to override , is not working**

Any help is appreciated
i want to override the values of predefined Css and add some css also...adding CSS is working but modifying the CSS value is not working

Comment: did you try !important

Comment: yes..but it did not work

Comment: now i did again adding ! important.....it worked now...but i want to know the reason ..why it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:host /deep/ .test{
       text-align:right !important; 
        color: red;
     }
```

worked for me..

any other solution?